# Send location to backend api at regular interval of time from react native

Tags: android, ios, react-native, api

I want to use `react-native-geolocation-service` to track the location but also every time send the location information to backend `API`. How can I do this without any performance issue?

```
Geolocation.watchPosition(
      (position) => {
        setLocation(position);
        console.log(position);
      },
      (error) => {
        setLocation(null);
        console.log(error);
      },
      {
        accuracy: {
          android: 'high',
          ios: 'best',
        },
        enableHighAccuracy: highAccuracy,
        distanceFilter: 0,
        interval: 5000,
        fastestInterval: 2000,
        forceRequestLocation: forceLocation,
        forceLocationManager: useLocationManager,
        showLocationDialog: locationDialog,
        useSignificantChanges: significantChanges,
      },
    );
```

Comment: "How can I do this without any performance issue?" This question is too broad. If you're facing specific performance issues that you can't figure out, please add them to your question.

Comment: @LonelyCpp I want to send the location details when location gets changed. Could you help me with this? Also I am confused with the way to handle multiple API call in backend as there might be large number of requests.